# Getting null value. Beginner

Tags: java

When use the interactions panel to run my code I get a null value before the result. for example when I enter:
1st word - google
2nd word - chrome

the result should be - gcohorgolme
but instead it is - nullgcohorgolme

Any ideas why?
Here is my code:

```
public class Collate{
  String result;
  String x;
  String y; 

  public String collate(String x, String y){

    for(int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++)
    {
      result += x.charAt(i);
      result += y.charAt(i);
    }
    return (result);
  }
}
```

Thanks a bunch!

Comment: initialize result first to empty string.

Comment: @xiriusly Please make that an answer...

Answer (score 7):

Make sure you initialize `result`:

```
  public String collate(String x, String y){
    result = ""; // <-- here

    for(int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++)
    {
      result += x.charAt(i);
      result += y.charAt(i);
    }
    return (result);
  }
```

Comment: @user2782378 Sure np, I'm glad I could help :)

Answer (score 3):

You haven't initialized your `result` value.

Remember that you should always initialize your variables. The `null` happens because your result is getting initialized an then converted to a String, which is `null`.

Answer (score 2):

initialize result first to empty string.

```
result = "";
```

Answer (score 2):

Initialize your `result` string, as `String result = "";`
This step should always be taken as a precaution, otherwise you may end up with a `null` output as you have here.

Answer (score 1):

`result += x.charAt(i)`
is equal to
`result = result + x.charAt(i)`
but `result` is null at first loop.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use a StringBuffer.

```
public static String collate(String x, String y){

    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();

    for(int i = 0; i < x.length(); i++)
    {
        result.append(x.charAt(i)).append(y.charAt(i));
    }

    return (result.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[4.3.1 Objects](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/) (from Java Language Specifications):

> The string concatenation operator `+`, which, when given a String
>   operand and a reference, will convert the reference to a String by invoking the
>   toString method of the referenced object (using "null" if either the reference
>   or the result of toString is a null reference), and then will produce a newly
>   created String that is the concatenation of the two strings

And here the `result` String was initialized with a null reference. So to get the desired result, you need to initialize the `result` as:

```
String result="";
```